# Rcp 4 feature how to use different versions of same plugin from different update sites

Tags: eclipse-rcp, osgi-bundle

My company has a featured based RCP 4 app. We use tycho to build the app with a predefined target platform. There are several plugins that are retrieved from separate p2 update sites that have different versions of the same plugin that are both needed for our app to run. However, it appears that Eclipse only picks up the latest version of the plugin when the code is executed so my app fails to run properly.

I considered an [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25973279/several-versions-of-a-plugin-in-a-feature-xml)  that had a similar problem, but the solution seemed to only deal with the issue where the plugins were defined in a dependency feature, not retrieved from a separate update site.

I've already tried including both versions of the plugins in the feature.xml with the correct "version=" value for each, but still only the latest version is used. What I want to know is how to get Eclipse to include both versions of the same plugin from the feature definition when the product is excecuted?

Comment: It is not possible to achieve this. Eclipse considers only the latest version of plugin while loading even if you have both the plugins available in the product.probably consider one of version of that "same" plugin and make other components compatible to it.

Comment: I wish I could Karthik. The problem is for whatever reason BIRT 4.4.1 requires two versions of three apache batik plugins. Since our app is using  BIRT, we are handcuffed by that dependency. I reached out to someone responsible for Eclipse BIRT development to find out why they don't they either remove the need for both or make them both available at the one BIRT update site? To no avail so far.